# populate the content of two files into a final file using pentaho(different fields)

Tags: pentaho

I have two files.
file A has, 3 columns
Sno,name,age,key,checkvalue

file B has 3 columns
Sno,title,age

I want to merge these two into final file C which has
Sno,name,age,key,checkvalue

I tried renaming "title" to "name" and then I used "Add constants" to add the other two field.

but, when i try to merge these, I get the below error

"
The name of field number 3 is not the same as in the first row received: you're mixing rows with different layout. Field [age  String] does not have the same name as field [age String].
"

How to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

After getting the input from file B. You use a `select values` and remove `title` column. Then you use a `Add constants` step and add new columns `name,key,checkvalue` and make `Set empty string?` to `Y`. Finally do the join accordingly. So it won't fail since both the files have same number of columns. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there was an issue with the fields ...  field mismatch. I used "Rename" option and it got fixed.